# Bootstrap Input Mask could not work, no errors shown in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a web app, used Bootstrap Input Mask  to do mask on the date input(add "-" between DD, MM, and YYYY)

However, the Bootstrap Input Mask  could not work, and there's no errors shown in the console.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.60/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="due_date" id="due_date" class="datepicker" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd-mm-yyyy" data-inputmask-placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa"> 

<script>
$('input').inputmask();

  $('#due_date').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
</script>
```

It is supposed to add "-" between DD, MM and YYYY input by user.
How could I find out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in the mask with a string as described in the docs here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#via-jquery-plugin

Use a string with the numbers: `inputmask('99-99-9999')`

I created a reduced test case for you here: https://codepen.io/MartinMuzatko/pen/ZEejEpL